# different number of adjacent nodes returned based on values in adjacent matrix

Tags: r, matrix, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to create a graph from an adjacent matrix but the resultant graph and its edges differ depending on what values are in the adjacent matrix

The cm_graph1 for example has 4 edges for node 12 (as expected), but cm_graph2 returns 2 edges (not expected, should be 4 - the same as cm_graph1)

It appears to not be including all `conductance2` when I do   `cs_matrix2[adj] <- conductance2`?

[image]

```
library(terra)
library(igraph)
library(Matrix)

set.seed(NULL)
set.seed(1)

r <- terra::rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, crs = "epsg:27700", xmin = -5, xmax = 5, ymin = -5, ymax = 5)
r[] <- runif(n = ncell(r), 1, 10)

plot(r)

neighbours <- 4

cells <- which(!is.na(terra::values(r)))
na_cells <- which(is.na(terra::values(r)))

adj <- terra::adjacent(x = r, cells = cells, directions = neighbours, pairs = TRUE)
adj <- adj[!adj[,2] %in% na_cells,]

elev_values <- terra::values(r)[,1]

rise <- (elev_values[adj[,2]] - elev_values[adj[,1]])
run <- terra::distance(terra::xyFromCell(r, adj[,1]), terra::xyFromCell(r, adj[,2]), lonlat = FALSE, pairwise = TRUE)

mathematical_slope <- rise/run

ncells <- length(cells) + length(na_cells)

cf1 <- function(x) {
  (6 * exp(-3.5 * abs(x + 0.05))) / 3.6
}

speed1 <- cf1(mathematical_slope)

conductance1 <- speed1/run

cs_matrix1 <- Matrix::Matrix(data = 0, nrow = ncells, ncol = ncells)
cs_matrix1[adj] <- conductance1
cs_matrix1[,12][cs_matrix1[,12] != 0]

cm_graph1 <- igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix(cs_matrix1, mode = "directed", weighted = TRUE)
cm_graph1[[12]]

cf2 <- function(x) {
  (1/((1337.8 * abs(x)^6) + (278.19 * abs(x)^5) - (517.39 * abs(x)^4) - (78.199 * abs(x)^3) + (93.419 * abs(x)^2) + (19.825 * abs(x)) + 1.64))
}

speed2 <- cf2(mathematical_slope)

conductance2 <- speed2/run

cs_matrix2 <- Matrix::Matrix(data = 0, nrow = ncells, ncol = ncells)
cs_matrix2[adj] <- conductance2
cs_matrix2[,12][cs_matrix2[,12] != 0]

cm_graph2 <- igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix(cs_matrix2, mode = "directed", weighted = TRUE)
cm_graph2[[12]]
```

Comment: When I run your code I get 4 edges for `cm_graph2[[12]]`

Comment: Thank you. weird. 

What version of igraph etc do you have? I have igraph_1.3.0, terra_1.6-7, Matrix_1.2-18

Comment: According to sessionInfo I've got Matrix_1.4-1, igraph_1.3.2, terra_1.5-34, running R 4.2.1 on Windows 11

Comment: Thank you - I'll try and update Matrix and see if that works!

Comment: Updating Matrix worked! Thanks so much for checking to see if you could run :). Feel free to answer and I'll upvote it